# having issues locating an element on selenium. Any tips?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am making a program that automatically runs through videos for me but I have run into a problem. when it comes to the frame_video_controls variable, The element cannot be located even though I have entered it into the iframe. I have also tried trying to locate it before entering the iframe to see if I was missing something.

How do I fix this issue?

```
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

def enter_iframe():
    iframe = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

    print('entering iframe...')


def exit_iframe():
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    print('exiting iframe')


def video_is_playing():
    sleep(1.5)
    print("video is playing...")

    enter_iframe()

    frame_video_controls = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="frame_video_controls"]')

    is_playing = 'block' in frame_video_controls.get_attribute('style')

    print("video is done")
    exit_iframe()

    return is_playing
```

Here is the error message

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="frame_video_controls"]"}
```

I left out some functions like the one that opens the page the videos are on to be more concise.

Comment: which `URL` if shared , I can try

Comment: the is URL is (https://r12.core.learn.edgenuity.com/Player/). I think you will not be able to enter it though. I can also screenshot the page with the elements on it if you want.

Comment: working URL would be better then screenshot. Maybe there is more `iframes` (or nested `iframes`) and you have to `switch_to` different frame. You can also use `driver.page_source` to see what HTML you have in this `iframe`. Eventually you can use another `sleep` to wait after changing frame. So there can be different problems and screenshot may not be useful for this.

Comment: have you tried `driver.find_element_by_id('frame_video_controls')` does it produce the same error?

Comment: yea I tried that. I also switched it to explicitly wait until the element was located for 30 seconds but the result was the same